# GridBagLayout - All components to top left

Tags: java, swing, alignment, gridbaglayout

How is it possible in the following GridBagLayout Code, to set alle components realtive to the top left corner. Now the components are always centered and it doesn't look that nice. I searched in many forums, but I didn't find any nice answer for my code.

```
private void initializeTabTiming()
  {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayoutTabTiming = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints lastConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints labelConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints titleConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    this.panelTabTiming = new JPanel(gridBagLayoutTabTiming);

    this.dateChooserStartDate = new JDateChooser(new Date());
    this.dateChooserStartDate.setDateFormatString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    this.dateChooserEndDate = new JDateChooser(new Date());
    this.dateChooserEndDate.setDateFormatString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    this.dateChooserPauseDate = new JDateChooser(new Date());
    this.dateChooserPauseDate.setDateFormatString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");

    lastConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    lastConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    lastConstraints.weightx = 1;
    lastConstraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    lastConstraints.insets = new Insets(8, 8, 8, 8);

    labelConstraints = (GridBagConstraints) lastConstraints.clone();
    labelConstraints.weightx = 0;
    labelConstraints.gridwidth = 1;

    titleConstraints = (GridBagConstraints) lastConstraints.clone();
    titleConstraints.gridwidth = 0;

    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.labelTabTimingTitle,
        titleConstraints);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.labelTabTimingTitle);

    JLabel temp = new JLabel("");
    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(temp,
        lastConstraints);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(temp);

    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.labelTabTimingStartDate,
        labelConstraints);
    this.labelTabTimingStartDate.setLabelFor(this.dateChooserStartDate);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.labelTabTimingStartDate);
    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.dateChooserStartDate,
        lastConstraints);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.dateChooserStartDate);

    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.labelTabTimingEndDate,
        labelConstraints);
    this.labelTabTimingEndDate.setLabelFor(this.dateChooserEndDate);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.labelTabTimingEndDate);
    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.dateChooserEndDate,
        lastConstraints);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.dateChooserEndDate);

    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.labelTabTimingPauseDate,
        labelConstraints);
    this.labelTabTimingPauseDate.setLabelFor(this.dateChooserPauseDate);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.labelTabTimingPauseDate);
    gridBagLayoutTabTiming.setConstraints(this.dateChooserPauseDate,
        lastConstraints);
    this.panelTabTiming.add(this.dateChooserPauseDate);
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are a few ways. My personal approach would be to add a transparent panel to the bottom/right position with a weightx/y of 1